# Getting multiple login requests in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, authentication, request

I'm getting too many login requests per second to my SQL Server hosted on AWS.[image]

These requests are continuous from so many days. Not able to find the reason. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The error gives you client address, check what program is running there

Comment: There are multiple IPs. They don't even belong my access.